# How to pass three specific times to the Flutter local notification function using the same notification ID?

Tags: flutter, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I want to receive three notifications at different times using the same notification ID. However, I have been able to send only one notification and couldn't manage to send the other two notifications.

packages

```
 flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
```

pass data to function code

```
// Generate a random notification ID
    final notificationID = Random().nextInt(10000);

    NotificationService().scheduleNotification(id:notificationID ,title: 'Scheduled Notification1 ${widget.petName} ', body: '$nextDate $notificationID  ${title.text}',
        scheduledNotificationDateTime: DateTime.parse('2023-05-18 16:46:00.000'),scheduledNotificationDateTime2: DateTime.parse('2023-05-18 16:48:00.000'),scheduledNotificationDateTime3: DateTime.parse('2023-05-18 16:49:00.000'));
```

**NotificationService() class**

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {required int id, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {

    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());

  }

  Future scheduleNotification(

      {required int id,
        String? title,
        String? body,
        String? payLoad,
        required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime, required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime2, required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime3}) async {


    print(" scheduledNotificationDateTime $scheduledNotificationDateTime");
    print(" body $body");
    print(" title $title");
    print(" id $id");

    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(

        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),

        await notificationDetails(),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,

        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);

  }

}
```

**void main**

[image]

How solve this and receive three notifications at different times using the same notification ID ?

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique. On writing to an existing id the notification is updated. 
For example You could use the DateTime in milliseconds as then id of when the notification will occur.